# Java Script function only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript/jQuery function is only running once and only the bottom part of the function is working. I can flip the order and then the other piece will work. What am I missing (using the Buzz audio API for the play and pause methods)?

```
var $playFromPlayerBar = $('.main-controls .play-pause');

var togglePlayFromPlayerBar = function(){
    if (currentSoundFile.pause() && $playFromPlayerBar.click){
        var $songNumberCell = getSongNumberCell(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);
        $songNumberCell.html(pauseButtonTemplate);
        $playFromPlayerBar.html(playerBarPauseButton);
        currentSoundFile.play();
    } 

    if (currentSoundFile.play() && $playFromPlayerBar.click){
        var $songNumberCell = getSongNumberCell(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);
        $songNumberCell.html(playButtonTemplate);
        $playFromPlayerBar.html(playerBarPlayButton);
        currentSoundFile.pause();
    }  

};

//load album when window loads
$(document).ready(function() {
    $playFromPlayerBar.click(togglePlayFromPlayerBar);
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: since you have placed the click function in document.ready it will be run only once when DOM is loaded

Comment: @ochi that is just fundamentally wrong

Comment: @charlietfl ok, I'll take it back :)

Comment: i was getting different errors in the console before this that are related to variables that aren't being used in the function

Comment: if you are rendering the toggle buttons again, you need to re-initiate the click event.  The new elements you added to the DOM has no idea that there is a click event.

Comment: to test it's the issue is related with re-rendering the toggle buttons, try jquery on('click') instead of .click()

Comment: and those conditionals don't make sense

Comment: open to refactor suggestions. The functionality needs to be that when you click the play button on the player bar, it turns to a pause button, the icon next to the song turns to a pause and the song plays. and visa versa. Can only get one of them to work at the moment.

Comment: can you also share your HTML?

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer at the bottom (utilized the sound.isPaused() method within the Buzz API to yield a boolean to determine if the sound was playing or not.) This allowed me to write a better conditional to check if it was true or false so I could assign the icons appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!! I figured it out.

```
var togglePlayFromPlayerBar = function(){
    if ($playFromPlayerBar.click){
        var $songNumberCell =           getSongNumberCell(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);

        if (currentSoundFile.isPaused()){
            $songNumberCell.html(pauseButtonTemplate);
            $playFromPlayerBar.html(playerBarPauseButton);
        } else {
            $songNumberCell.html(playButtonTemplate);
            $playFromPlayerBar.html(playerBarPlayButton);
        }

        currentSoundFile.togglePlay();
    }
};


//load album when window loads
$(document).ready(function() {
    $playFromPlayerBar.click(togglePlayFromPlayerBar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The binding may be at fault here, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $playFromPlayerBar.click(function() {
        togglePlayFromPlayerBar();
    });
});
```

Also you need to call the click function, you're doing this in your conditional expressions:

```
$playFromPlayerBar.click
```

You should be doing this:

```
$playFromPlayerBar.click()
```

Comment: @charlietfl it could work, anything's possible in javascript ;-)

Comment: the function does run again now (which is an improvement) however only the bottom portion of the function runs (which is the following):



`if (currentSoundFile.play() && $playFromPlayerBar.click){
        var $songNumberCell = getSongNumberCell(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);
        $songNumberCell.html(playButtonTemplate);
        $playFromPlayerBar.html(playerBarPlayButton);
        currentSoundFile.pause();
    }`

Comment: @Rapid99 you need to call the click function in your if checks.